# How to change math quiz difficulty based on game level user clicks? Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, math

I am creating a simple android math game where the user is presented with 4 game levels.

I'm trying to figure out how I would change the length of the math questions based on the level the user has chosen. How would I do this? Would it be an if statement? So if the user chooses hard for example, it would display 5 * 10 / 3.

I have implemented this in the game class(game class):

```
private static final String TAG = "math Game" ;
public static final String KEY_LEVEL = "org.example.math.level" ;
public static final int LEVEL_EASY = 0;
public static final int LEVEL_MEDIUM = 1;
public static final int LEVEL_HARD = 2;
```

And this is the mainactivity class for the difficulties

```
private static final String TAG = "Math Game" ;

private void openNewGameDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.new_game_title)
        .setItems(R.array.level,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface
                dialoginterface, int i) {
                startGame(i);
            }
        })
        .show();
}

private void startGame(int i) {
    Log.d(TAG, "clicked on " + i);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Game.class);
    intent.putExtra(Game.KEY_LEVEL, i);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is the array.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<array name="level">
<item>@string/easy_label</item>
<item>@string/medium_label</item>
<item>@string/hard_label</item>
</array>
</resources>
```

How would I do if statements or maybe switch to change the difficulty on the question based on what the user clicks. Each game level would have a different length of question but I'm not sure how to do it based on what level the user clicks

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you store questions in files?

Comment: Now no but later on through the game, I might do

Comment: Hm, you better decide before coding. This decision will have some impact on your design. Anyway, I'll provide an answer for two possible ways I see you most probably going to store your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In case you use files to store the questions:

Use an if..else if..else statement to pick the appropriate file in the Game.class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String level = intent.getStringExtra(Game.KEY_LEVEL);

File myFile;
if (Game.KEY.equals(getResources().getText(R.string.easy_label))) {
   myFile = new File(insert here the path of the file that contains the easy questions);
} else if (Game.KEY.equals(getResources().getText(R.string.medium_label))) {
   myFile = new File(insert here the path of the file that contains the medium questions);
} else {
   myFile = new File(insert here the path of the file that contains the hard questions);
}
```

### In case you decide to store all the questions as Question objects:

Create a Question class like this:

```
class Question {
     private String questionText;
     private String category;
     // more vars
     // Setters and Getters

     public getARandomQuestion(String category) {
         // write code here to return a random questions that has belongs to the Category category.
     }
```

and then do the same if..else if..else loop as above but this time the body of if, else if and else should be different:

```
if (Game.KEY.equals(getResources().getText(R.string.easy_label))) {
        Question theQuestion = new Question();
        theQuestion.getARandomQuestion("easy");    
} else if (Game.KEY.equals(getResources().getText(R.string.medium_label))) {
        Question theQuestion = new Question();
        theQuestion.getARandomQuestion("medium");     
} else {
        Question theQuestion = new Question();
        theQuestion.getARandomQuestion("hard");     
}
```

Of course this can go further by creating a Category enumeration as well to pass Categories instead of Strings to the getARandomQuestion method.